# Visualisation of principal components (PC)

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I am using `ggplot2` in R to produce the plot from the code:

final_flights <- augment(flights_model, flights_tbl) %>% collect()'
`final_flights`

```
# A tibble: 327,346 x 22
    year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time
   <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>    <int>          <int>
 1  2013     1     1      517            515         2      830            819
 2  2013     1     1      533            529         4      850            830
 3  2013     1     1      542            540         2      923            850
 4  2013     1     1      544            545        -1     1004           1022
 5  2013     1     1      554            600        -6      812            837
 6  2013     1     1      554            558        -4      740            728
 7  2013     1     1      555            600        -5      913            854
 8  2013     1     1      557            600        -3      709            723
 9  2013     1     1      557            600        -3      838            846
10  2013     1     1      558            600        -2      753            745
# ... with 327,336 more rows, and 14 more variables: arr_delay <dbl>,
#   carrier <chr>, flight <int>, tailnum <chr>, origin <chr>, dest <chr>,
#   air_time <dbl>, distance <dbl>, hour <dbl>, minute <dbl>, time_hour <dttm>,
#   PC1 <dbl>, PC2 <dbl>, PC3 <dbl>
```

I have tried already:

```
    ggplot(final_flights, aes(PC1, PC2)) +   
      geom_point(aes(colour=air_time))


    ggplot(final_flights, aes(PC1, PC2, PC3))+ 
      geom_point(aes(colour=air_time, distance, dep_time))

    ml_predict(kmeans_model) %>%
      collect() %>%
      ggplot(aes(air_time, distance, dep_time)) +
      geom_point(aes(air_time, distance, dep_time, col = factor(prediction+1)),
     size=2, alpha=0.5)+
     geom_point(data=kmeans_model$k, aes(air_time, distance, dep_time),
      pch='x', size=12)+
      scale_color_discrete(name="Predicted cluster")

> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics:  Warning: Ignoring unknown
> aesthetics:  Error: Column 3 must be named.
```

I want to produce the ggplot model with two principal components, which variable explains the clustering in the data

Comment: Please formulate more clear a question

Comment: how can i produce ggplot model with two PC where it explaining clustering of the data based on the formula:  ml_kmeans(formula = ~air_time+distance+dep_time, k=3)
i did try several, but the last one im looking for always gives me an error and does not plot results: ml_predict(kmeans_model) %>%
  collect() %>%
  ggplot(aes(air_time, distance, dep_time)) +
  geom_point(aes(air_time, distance, dep_time, col = factor(prediction+1)),
 size=2, alpha=0.5)+
 geom_point(data=kmeans_model$k, aes(air_time, distance, dep_time),
  pch='x', size=12)+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Predicted cluster")

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(flights_tbl)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(flights_tbl, 20))`.

Comment: 1) You must name the **3rd aesthetics** in `aes(air_time, distance, dep_time)`, the 1st is the `x` coordinate and the 2nd is the `y` coordinate. 2) You don't need to repeat the aesthetics in `geom_point`. 3) It's not `col`, it's `colour` or `color`. (`col` is in base graphics, not `ggplot2`.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas i have added code for the ggplot, i need to use ggplot to visialise the data